# Readonly access to session in a web service call?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms, session-state

We have a .net asmx web service that gets called from javascript (using ASP.Net AJAX), and requires access to Session.

```
[WebMethod(true)]
public string DoSomethingOnTheServer() { }
```

We're running into the problem of session being locked on a read/write request. Is there any way to mark a web service method as requiring read-only access to Session?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

This is a really old thread, but i stumbled on it in my search for an answer to the same question.

I found the answer else where, and will leave it here for other internets in my place:

In Global.asax you can specify for each request, what access the request should have to the session object, and thereby if it should block or not.

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This will set the session to read only for asmx services
    // This will make the asmx services non blocking for other requests as it doesnt lock the session object
    if (Context.Request.Path.Contains(".asmx/"))
    {
        Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
    }
}
```

This way asmx services always only have read only access to the session and will not block other requests

Comment: Mikael, you are my hero

Comment: I've been trying to solve this problem for over 30 hours. It works for web methods, to make the method itself readonly, which isn't possible in ASP.NET forms. Just use `Contains("MethodName")`.

Comment: Excellent cross sharing of a solution, we can use this to address our concurrency issue by using in our base service constructors and our own Attribute annotations!

Answer (score 5):

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx page seems to suggest that the answer is "no" - you cannot mark a WebSerivce as having `EnableSessionState=ReadOnly`.

> If you are making simultaneous Web service calls from the same process, the requests will be serialized at the server so that only one will execute at any one time. Unlike .ASPX pages that have support for read-only access to the HttpSessionState object, which allows for simultaneous processing of multiple requests, there is no such capability with ASP.NET Web services. All Web method calls with sessions enabled have read/write access and will be serialized within each session.

Warning: That article is  old (2002).

Comment: old, but seems to still apply :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx.aspx) of the WebMethod Attribute there are several possible properties, so I'm not sure what the 'true' value in your WebMethod Attribute going to do.

Have you tried:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
```

According to [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480509.aspx) that should give you full access to the session.

Comment: The problem is that method allows both read and write access...I'm looking for a way to just turn on read access (turning on write access causes blocking when you have multiple simultaneous requests). However, I don't believe there is a way.

Comment: Ah ha, now I see...
Now that I've done a little more searching it doesn't make much sense that you can set a Page to have read only access, but not a Web Service.
What if you put the WebMethods in a aspx page (exposed as WebMethods) and set the page's EnableSessionState property to ReadOnly?
It isn't the best solution, but it might work.

Comment: Putting webmethods in aspx page with  EnableSessionState property to ReadOnly works. Requests will be processed concurrently. Thanks @PhillFox