# Two separate ajax calls with one running in an interval but depending on the other to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have got two calls that have to run in parallel. One is supposed to continuously fetch data and update a table and it should only stop when the result of the other ajax function is returned. I use setinterval() funtion to run the continuous fetching. For some reason, the results of the continuously fetched data only come later after the single call of the second ajax function has completed. Here is my code.

```
function runNightly() {
   
    let timer = null;
    

    $.when(

        timer = setInterval(updateServicesTable, 500),
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "EndOfDay.asmx/runEOD",
            contentType: "application/json",
            
            success: function (responseFromServer) {

                $.each(responseFromServer, function (index, res) {

                    console.log("EOD result :" + res);//Result from EOD

                });

            },
            complete: function () {
                setTimeout(stopTask, 0, timer);
            },
            failed: function () {
                setTimeout(stopTask, 0, timer);
            }
        })
        

    ).then(function () {
        console.log('Done');
    });

}
```

Here is my code for continuously fetching data:

```
function updateServicesTable() {
    console.log("fetch services");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "EndOfDay.asmx/fetchServices",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (responseFromServer) {

            var row = $("[id*=ServicesGrid] tr:last-child").clone(true);//Get the last row, its always a null
            $("[id*=ServicesGrid] tr").not($("[id*=ServicesGrid] tr:first-child")).remove();//remove all rows except the last

            let objdata = $.parseJSON(responseFromServer.d);
            console.log(objdata);//results obtained
            if (objdata != null) {
                let table = objdata["Table1"];
                let rowNum;
                for (rowNum in table) {
                    if (table[rowNum] != null) {
                        /*Update the row variable*/
                        $("td", row).eq(0).html(table[rowNum][0]);//code
                        $("td", row).eq(1).html(table[rowNum][1]);//descriptions
                        $("td", row).eq(2).html(table[rowNum][2]);//process flag
                        $("td", row).eq(3).html(table[rowNum][6]);//status code
                        $("[id*=ServicesGrid]").append(row);//append the row to the gridview
                        row = $("[id*=ServicesGrid] tr:last-child").clone(true); //get the new last row


                    }
                }
            }

        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log("calling services complete");
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `Asp.Net session state` used by the web service? If so, that might be the cause... Only one request can have write access to a specific session at any one time.

Comment: You have to use   clearTimeout(myVar) to clear timeout

Comment: @user1429080, I do use a session in the web service but only to read from it rather than writing to it

Comment: @Rali, I do use the clearTimeout method in the stopTask() function to stop the timer

Comment: @AinemigishaAlvin If you only need read access to the session, then have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44821559/1429080). Maybe you can use the trick there in your solution..?